# create rows if missing in pandas df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Current data :

```
  |ID | DT     | STATE | V|
  |1  | 201901 | PA    | 1|
  |1  | 201902 | PA    | 6|
  |2  | 201902 | PA    | 3|
  |1  | 201902 | CA    | 3|
  |2  | 201901 | CA    | 1|
```

I want to create rows with all combinations of `ID`, `DT` and `STATE` with `V` being 0 where its not available like this :

```
  |ID | DT     | STATE | V|
  |1  | 201901 | PA    | 1|
  |1  | 201902 | PA    | 6|
  |1  | 201901 | CA    | 0|
  |1  | 201902 | CA    | 3|
  |2  | 201901 | PA    | 0|
  |2  | 201902 | PA    | 3|
  |2  | 201901 | CA    | 1|
  |2  | 201902 | CA    | 0|
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `MultiIndex` index then `reindex`

```
idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.ID.unique(),df.DT.unique(),df.STATE.unique()])
df=df.set_index(['ID','DT','STATE']).reindex(idx,fill_value=0).reset_index()
df
   level_0  level_1 level_2  V
0        1   201901      PA  1
1        1   201901      CA  0
2        1   201902      PA  6
3        1   201902      CA  3
4        2   201901      PA  0
5        2   201901      CA  1
6        2   201902      PA  3
7        2   201902      CA  0
```

Comment: Nice~ +1 Very similar answer. Slightly more concise. It's a good idea to use `set_index` rather than `groupby` unless there are multiple rows for `['ID','DT','STATE']` where that info might need to be summarize by a `.mean()`, `.sum()`, etc. -- otherwise there would be duplicates. Is that correct @YOBEN_S ?

Answer (score -1):

`groupby` the first three columns and `.reindex` by those columns and `.sort_values` as desired.

input:

```
    ID  DT  STATE   V
0   1   201901  PA  1
1   1   201902  PA  6
2   2   201902  PA  3
3   1   201902  CA  3
4   2   201901  CA  1
```

code

```
i = [df['ID'].unique(), df['DT'].unique(), df['STATE'].unique()]
df = df.groupby(['ID', 'DT', 'STATE']).sum() \
   .reindex(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(i, names=['ID', 'DT', 'STATE']), fill_value=0) \
   .reset_index().sort_values(['ID', 'STATE', 'DT'], ascending=[True,False,True])
df
```

output:

```
    ID  DT      STATE   V
0   1   201901  PA      1
8   1   201902  PA      6
2   1   201901  CA      0
10  1   201902  CA      3
256 2   201901  PA      0
264 2   201902  PA      3
258 2   201901  CA      1
266 2   201902  CA      0
```